# Sequencing Java 6 update 24/25 in appv

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, java, application-server, app-v

Has anyone attempted to sequence any java runtime with success?
I want to run it virtualy and I thought that maybe i could use the middleware option.
I was just about to test it out but I thought I would find out before I potentialy spend a lot of time on this.
If you have can you add some comments on how you went about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sequenced it just like a plugin such as adobe flash player and silverlight.

It worked.

Thanks